# How to get cell name from an excel sheet in C# using late binding?

Tags: c#, excel, late-binding

I am trying to get the cell name like `A1,B1,A2,B2` from an excel sheet.

Here is my code

```
object objCellText = Cells.GetType().InvokeMember("Item", 
                        BindingFlags.GetProperty,null,Cells, 
                        new object[] { RowIndex, ColIndex });

var CellText = objCellText.GetType().InvokeMember("Value",
                        BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, objCellText, null);

var CellName = objCellText.GetType().InvokeMember("Name",
                        BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, objCellText, null);
```

In the code, `Name` property is not working.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why are you using reflection instead of dynamic typing ? Use `dynamic` instead of object so you can write `Cells.Item`, or `cell.Value`

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos i am not only getting a Item or value but also need cell background color,font styles etc., so i am using object..

Comment: Using `dynamic` allows you to call them as well. It was added to make exactly such scenarios easier *and* faster.

Answer (score 0):

That's because a Cell's name is *not* its address. You can name a cell or range of cells with a descriptive name, eg "Expenses". `A2` or `A2:B2` are the addresses of a single cell or range of cells. A named range can be used in a formula, eg `SUM(Expenses)` just like a range address `SUM(A1:B2)`.